# how to get recycleview Item height and set as container height

Tags: android, fragment, android-recyclerview

I've a recycle view inside a fragment (max item will show in list is 5), I want to set the fragment container size according to the number of items showing in list,

What I want is user shouldn't need to scroll the list to see all the items?

Answer (score 0):

A RecyclerView is intended for showing many items in a scrolling list.
That's where it gets its name from. It efficiently ***Recycles*** the ***Views*** for items that have been scrolled off screen.

From what you are describing, you are only ever showing a maximum of 5 items and you want them all on the screen at the same time, so you don't need a RecyclerView.

Just add your items to a LinearLayout and set the layoutHeight of each item as 0dp and the layoutWeight of each item as 1. That will distribute the items evenly across the full height of the LinearLayout.

#### Edit

If you want the fragment to adjust it's height according to the number of items, then set the height to WRAP_CONTENT for the fragment container, LinearLayout, and each of the items you add to the linear layout.

Comment: well in my app i have this issue on Main Screen where it show only recent 5 transactions, and there is a separate section where you can see all transaction, so i'm using the same fragment in Main_View And transaction list

Comment: I think it will take you a lot more time trying to get a RecyclerView to do something it is not designed for, than to put together another simple fragment that handles the 5 transaction case. You can copy a lot of the same logic from your full RecyclerView fragment to populate the 5 transaction LinearLayout fragment.

Comment: I just found this link but, I'm always getting height as zero  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30711305/get-height-for-recyclerview-child-views-at-runtime